# Perform a clean install on my new Asus laptop - where can I find certain OEM software?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I just got a new Asus laptop from Best Buy and I really want to do a clean install. I think I found on Asus site where I can get all drivers except I can't find the Power2Go software.

Can you please tell me about your experiences around this issue of getting a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when I do a clean reload of a laptop, I try to find Free/Open Source Software replacements for any useful utilities that came loaded by the OEM.  In the case of Power2Go, Wikipedia has this categorized as "optical disc authoring software" made by CyberLink:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/CyberLink

Wikipedia has a list of optical disc authoring software, many of which are F/OSS solutions:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_optical_disc_authoring_software

My personal preference is CD Burner XP:

http://cdburnerxp.se/

Answer (score 1):

Most PC makers only allow you to install bundled software using the Factory Restore media or restore partition, Dell is the only one that I know of that allows you to download a copy of pre-installed (bundled) software titles.

iszi has the best advice, find alternative softwares that do the same thing, many are free like CDburner XP.